# I want to take inputs of 2d vector using ranged based for loop. How can i do?

Tags: c++, loops, vector, 2d, cin

As a beginner i am exploring multiple methods to increase my clarity, so i did this question.

```cpp
// no problem with this looping method
vector <vector<int>> vec(n,vector<int>(m));
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < m; j++){
        cin >> vec[i][j];
    }
}
```

```cpp
// but i tried in this way using ranged based loop, and it doesn't work. 
// I think i need a few modification here, so i need your help.
for(vector<int> v1d : vec){
    for(int x : v1d){
        cin >> x;
    }
}
```

Same code, just cin replaced by cout, i can print that vector elements easily.
but in case of cin i am having problem.
no error, but it's not working.

Thanks

Comment: You need to use references when you want to modify what you are looping over.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to take the values by reference in the range base for-loops. Otherwise `v1d` and `x` will be copies and any changes you make to those copies will not be affecting the content of `vec` in any way.

```cpp
for(auto& v1d : vec) {   // or: std::vector<int>& v1d
//      ^
    for(auto& x : v1d) { // or: int& x
//          ^
        std::cin >> x;
    }
}
```

Comment: @fabian Yeah, I guess it's neater to be consistent. I updated it.